# Styles for 'after' differ in browsers

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm displaying a star after input box using `:after`. The styles are being rendered differently by different browsers. How can i make this appear similar in all the browsers. Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omLc9nfe/2/) in different browsers where in you can see the difference.

Comment: normalize the input? `input {padding:2px;border:1px solid;margin:2px;}`

Comment: even then able to see a little difference. star is touching input field in firefox while not in chrome. @AlexK.

Comment: Lots of things looks different in different browsers! That's why @l2aelba mentioned CSS reset -it's a CSS stylesheet designed to give you a common base to build from.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height for a:after and give custom style to input (to avoid differences in padding, border, etc)

http://jsfiddle.net/omLc9nfe/7/

```
.a:after{
    content:'*';
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-8px;
    right:-8px;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    text-align:center;
}
.a{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
input {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
}
```

i've checked with safari, firefox and chrome.

[image][image][image]